# Windows forgets self-signed certificate after reboot

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, ssl, certificate

I have a self-signed website certificate. When using it I have two Windows 10 machines that forget the self-signed certificate every time after windows reboot. It only happens in those two machines. I have tried many different machines and they keep remembering it even after reboots. The behaviour happens in different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).

It seems to be something in the setting of those windows instances. But I can not figure out what seems to be the cause for this behaviour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In which certificates section did you put the certificate? In user's section or computer?